# Atom editor: autocomplete-python package doesn't work, Jedi problem?

Tags: python, autocomplete, atom-editor, jedi

I have installed Jedi 0.18 on Python 3.8.8 using Miniconda, when I install the autocomplete-python package on Atom i get this error:

```
Looks like this error originated from Jedi. Please do not report such issues in autocomplete-python issue tracker. Report them directly to Jedi. Turn off outputProviderErrors setting to hide such errors in future. Traceback output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aless\.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib/completion.py", line 378, in watch
    self._process_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\aless\.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib/completion.py", line 338, in _process_request
    script = jedi.api.Script(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source'
```

adding the paths to the settings of the package doesn't work.
Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please report this to the autocomplete-python issue tracker. They need to change some small things, because Jedi's API has changed. Otherwise you can still use 0.17.2.

Comment: Possibly the same issue -
https://github.com/autocomplete-python/autocomplete-python/issues/456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the current jedi version you have either with pip, or by deleting the site package folders and then do an install on version 0.17.2 instead:

```
pip uninstall jedi

pip install jedi==0.17.2
```

This worked instantly for me. I spent almost 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Yeah I stopped using Atom and migrated to VS Code because of this. Python support has been ridiculous on Atom, over the last 8 months no python packages on atom have been updated.
What a joke!

Comment: Yea, python support has sadly eroded. Sublime 4 is out btw